# Hide NotifyIcon after debugger stop

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I`m using Visual Studio 2012 and have application, which creates notifyIcon and show it, if i close application then notifyIcon hides, but if I stop debugger then closes only forms, but notifyIcon still visible while I not hover it with mouse.

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2010 to hide notifyIcon when I stop debugger?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.

There are Windows APIs that tell the shell to show and hide the notification icons, and the NotifyIcon class just wraps those APIs.

If you stop the debugger, the NotifyIcon object never gets the chance to call the API to hide the notification icon. Just mouse over it; the shell will realize the application that asked for the icon is not running, and will remove the icon.

This issue can happen for any application that manages notification icons, not just Visual Studio.

Comment: It ought to be possible to write a VS extension that sends a message (I don't know which) to the notification area when you click stop.

Comment: Well...[Shell_NotifyIcon(DWORD dwMessage, PNOTIFYICONDATA lpdata)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx) is the Windows API in question; the extension would have to keep track of what NotifyIcon classes were in the project and watch for them to call `Shell_NotifyIcon` in order to catch the `hWnd` and `uID` to use to remove the icon. But anything's possible, I suppose :)